Convergence of gradient descent to critical point
Does there exist a generalization of this theorem by Yurii Nesterov in Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization (2004) which relaxes the convexity assumption and shows that gradient descent converges to a critical point?

Corollary 2.1.2. If the learning rate $h=1/L$ and $f$ is a convex and differentiable $L$-Lipschitz function, then performing gradient descent for $k$ iterations yields a solution which satisfies $$f(x_k) - f^* \leq \dfrac{2L \lVert x_0 - x^* \rVert^2}{k+4}$$


Can you give a specific pointer to the theorem number and/or a page? The book is about 230 pages long.

It depends a bit on what theorem you want. The premises and results can be a little subtle (note, e.g., there's a difference between "converges to a critical point" and "value converges to the value at a critical point") But if you're interested in stochastic gradient descent, these slides give a nice survey of various conditions and results: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6787/2017fa/Lecture7.pdf

Thanks all for your replies! David - this is Corollary 2.1.2 in Nesterov

Thanks Martin! Very good point - I believe my colleagues and I are looking for a variant which converges to a critical point but would be open to learning about either. As for SGD I believe we are looking more for classical gradient descent, but will take a look!

@Kyle Do you want to use a fixed step-size for the gradient updates, or a (positive) variable step-size with a given maximum admissible size?

@ABIM Either or! (as long as GD converges :)) Thanks!
